# How to reverse geocode the continent using CLGeocoder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

Surprisingly, I wasn't able to find ANY meaningfull information in 30 minutes of search in all the right places..it's suspicious, I think I am doing something wrong.
I would add, that the solution should be without requiring third party code or webservices..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually wrote a category to address this caveat in the CLPlacemark class. 
It currently uses the -ISOCountryCode property to map it to its correspondent continent.

https://github.com/Hecktorzr/Transcontinental

Answer (score 5):

How are you using the CLGeocoder at the moment. Without seeing some code not much we can suggest ...

However, if you are trying to get information on where the user is or where a location is you can use this:

```
{
  CLLocationManager *location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  [location setDelegate:self];
  [location startUpdatingLocation];
  [location setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

  CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
  [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location.location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
      CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

      NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", placemark.country, placemark.ISOcountryCode, placemark.postalCode, placemark.administrativeArea, placemark.locality, placemark.subLocality, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare);

      [geocoder release];
      [location release];
    }];
}
```

Comment: This will return information about where the user is. the location plugged into the geocoded can obviously be a different one. Hope this helps and this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Mine code is exactly the same - I subscribe to the location manager, get a momentary CLLocation from it and through some block code, I get a placemark, which contains many (nice) things, but surprisingly not the continent. I kind of knew, it is not there, I hoped for some alternative class or solution.

Comment: Oh ok, not sure about continent but i know of a 3rd party reverse geocoded that works pretty well. May return something useful if you want me to dig it out.

Comment: Oh, I wouldn't want to waste your time, 3rd party solutions are a curse anyway, at least I have that experience through the years..this is why I was hoping for built-in class. I will submit this to Apple when their bug reporting platform starts to work again.