# How to identify the country by clicking on the map?

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

For example, touch a region of the map and saw the alert with the name of the country, the clicked

Comment: Why would you want to saw an alert? One, the alert isn't wooden, two, why doesn't an entire alert suffice?

Comment: How to reverse geocode the continent using CLGeocoder?[1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8696066/how-to-reverse-geocode-the-continent-using-clgeocoder

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/08/simplegeo-ios-started-tutorial/ If not, please help with what you want exactely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all figured out

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:55.755773 longitude:37.617761];
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:location completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@ %@", placemark.country, placemark.ISOcountryCode, placemark.postalCode, placemark.administrativeArea, placemark.locality, placemark.subLocality, placemark.thoroughfare, placemark.subThoroughfare);
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

Search for "reverse geocoding"